# div alignment is not properly working on the header with menu

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I try to align my menu properly but it's not working properly. So the way it's done is that when you arrive on my website and not logged in, the header below is displayed:

[image]

When the user is loggedin, the `login/register` is replaced by a scrolldown menu which is triggered by the click of an avatar. The scroll down works fine but the render of the menu is not aligned as you see below:

[image]

I am not able to make the avatar and the menu properly aligned as it's done at first.

below is code:

```
const fakeName = "First Last";
const isGuest = false;

const StyledProfileMenu = withStyles({
    paper: {
      border: '1px none',
      borderRadius: "21px",
      boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
    },
  })((props) => (
    <Menu
      elevation={0}
      getContentAnchorEl={null}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'left',
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'center',
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  ));

  const StyledProfileMenuItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        margin: "2px 30px 1px 10px",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
        fontSize: "",
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: '#ff7255'},

        '&:focus': {
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: '#ff7255'},
    },
  }))(MenuItem);


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      boxShadow: "none",
      backgroundColor:  "#ffffff",
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    logo: {
        width:"214px",
        height:"28px",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(20),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3)

    },
    search: {
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: "21px",
        backgroundColor: "#f4f7f8",
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        width: "467px",
        height: "40px",
       // [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
       //   marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      //    width: 'auto',
       // },
      },
      searchIcon: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1, 2),
        height: '18px',
        width: '18px',
        position: 'absolute',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: "#cecece"
      },
      inputRoot: {
        color: "#cecece",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
        fontSize: "18px"
      },
      inputInput: {
        paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
        width: "467px",
      //  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      //    width: '20ch',
      //  },
      },
      menu: {
        display: "flex",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        margin: "auto",
      },
      menuItem: {
        color: "#cecece",
        fontSize: "20px",
        fontFamily: "Fredoka One",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: '#ff7255'},
        '&:focus': {
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            color: '#ff7255'},
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      },
      userName: {
          fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
          fontWeight: "Bold",
          borderBottom: '3px solid #ff7255',
          textAlign: "center",
          margin: "2px 10px 2px 10px",
          paddingBottom: "2px"
      }
  }));




function Header(){

    let loginOrProfile;

    const styles = useStyles();

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const profileMenu = 
        <div>
        <IconButton
            aria-controls="customized-menu"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleClick}>
            <Avatar alt="Avatar" src={DefaultAvatar} /> 
            <ArrowDropDownIcon style={{ color: "#ff7255" }}/>       
        </IconButton>
        <StyledProfileMenu
            id="customized-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}>
            <p className={styles.userName}> {fakeName} </p>
            <StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <ListItemText primary={TextContents.MenuProfile} />
            </StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <ListItemText primary={TextContents.MenuMessages} />
            </StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <ListItemText primary={TextContents.MenuSettings} />
            </StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <StyledProfileMenuItem>
            <ListItemText primary={TextContents.MenuLogout} />
            </StyledProfileMenuItem>
        </StyledProfileMenu>
        </div>;

    const loginMenu = 
        <Typography className={styles.menuItem}> {TextContents.MenuLoginRegister} </Typography>;


    if(isGuest){
        loginOrProfile = loginMenu;
    } else {
        loginOrProfile = profileMenu;
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" className={styles.root}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <img src={VillageLogo} alt="logo" className={styles.logo}/>
                    <div className={styles.search}>
                        <div className={styles.searchIcon}>
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </div>
                        <InputBase
                            placeholder={TextContents.SearchPlaceHolder}
                            classes={{
                                root: styles.inputRoot,
                                input: styles.inputInput,
                            }}
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.menu}>
                        <Typography className={styles.menuItem}> {TextContents.MenuDiscover} </Typography>
                        <Typography className={styles.menuItem}> {TextContents.MenuCreate} </Typography>
                        <Typography className={styles.menuItem}> {TextContents.MenuHiW} </Typography>
                        {isGuest && loginMenu}
                        {!isGuest && profileMenu}
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>

            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}



export default Header
```

If someone may have any idea how to make the alignment proper, I would be super happy

Comment: have you tried using `align-items: center` alongside `display: flex`?

Comment: works just fine

Comment: mind if I put in an answer instead?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: as in, can I answer the question instead of putting it in a comment as I get no rep this way? :(

Comment: if indeed the answer above did actually work for you

Comment: yes my answer was too short. The answer you gave me works perfectly. Thanks a lot 
@RedBaron

Comment: in case you may have an idea, I have posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62298224/build-a-proper-alignment-for-a-footer @RedBaron

Comment: ok I have posted answer for this one if you can accept :). I will look at other question now!

Comment: done, one more time. Thanks. I am a newby in css / react and kind of struggling to understand all the positins

Comment: Seb, no worries :). happy to help. I have answered the other q. let me know how you get on

Comment: @RedBaron there is no changes

Comment: lets keep talking on that question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```