# build a proper alignment for a footer

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, footer

I just review a footer to make it better using a different UI framework. I try to align it but it's not properly working. The right side is not is overlapping. I tried using `<div>` and apply the style to set up a different element.

The issue I have is the text `Follow` behind the button need to be aligned with the icons and the image, input form, button and text 'Follow' and icons must be aligned in one single line and centred in the middle of the page.

The copyright text on the second line is properly aligned

[image]

I tried different combination but still not properly done

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Toolbar, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import VillageLogo from '../assets/images/village-logo.svg';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import TextContents from '../theme/TextContents';
import FacebookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Facebook';
import TwitterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Twitter';
import InstagramIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Instagram';
import LinkedInIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LinkedIn';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      display: "flex",
      boxShadow: "none",
      backgroundColor:  "#ffffff",
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    },
    logo: {
        width:"214px",
        height:"28px",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(20),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3)

    },
    subscribe: {
        display: "flex",
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: "21px",
        backgroundColor: "#f4f7f8",
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        width: "467px",
        height: "40px",
       // [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
       //   marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      //    width: 'auto',
       // },
      },
      inputRoot: {
        color: "#cecece",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
        fontSize: "18px"
      },
      inputInput: {
        paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
        width: "467px",
      //  [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      //    width: '20ch',
      //  },
      },
      whiteButton:{
        borderRadius: 21, 
        fontSize: '14px' ,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ff7255",
        boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
        paddingTop: "5px",
        paddingBottom: "7px",
        paddingLeft: "20px",
        paddingRight: "20px",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff", 
        borderColor: "#ffffff",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
      },
      textFollow:{
        fontSize: '14px' ,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ff7255",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
      },
      textCopy:{
        fontSize: '14px' ,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ff7255",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
      },
      socialIcon:{
          width: '18px',
          height:'18px',
          color: '#ff7255'
      },
      followDesc:{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        margin: "auto",
      },
      footerMenu:{
          display: "flex",
          position: 'relative'
      }

  }));


function Footer(){

    const styles = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" className={styles.root}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <img src={VillageLogo} alt="logo" className={styles.logo}/>
                    <div className={styles.footerMenu}>
                        <div className={styles.subscribe}>
                            <InputBase
                                placeholder={TextContents.SearchPlaceHolder}
                                classes={{
                                    root: styles.inputRoot,
                                    input: styles.inputInput,
                                }}
                                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'subscribe' }}/>
                            <Button className={styles.whiteButton}> {TextContents.Join}</Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.followDesc}>
                            <p className={styles.textFollow}>{TextContents.Follow}</p>
                            <FacebookIcon className={styles.socialIcon}/>
                            <TwitterIcon className={styles.socialIcon}/>
                            <InstagramIcon className={styles.socialIcon}/>
                            <LinkedInIcon className={styles.socialIcon}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
                <div>
                    <p className={styles.textCopy}>{TextContents.Copyright}</p>
                </div>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
}



export default Footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

I added `justifyContent: "center"`

```
      followDesc:{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        margin: "auto",
      },
```

oh and you need to get rid of `margin` on the `p` element.

try adding somewhere:

`p { margin: 0 }` or change the `p` to a `div` element instead

[image]

edit =====

to replicate it like the above do 2 things

add `minWidth: 75px` in here:

```
  textFollow: {
    fontSize: "14px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#ff7255",
    fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
    minWidth: '75px'
  },
```

and move this line: `<Button className={styles.whiteButton}> join</Button>` underneath this line: `<div className={styles.followDesc}>`

so it looks like this:

```
<div className={styles.followDesc}>
  <Button className={styles.whiteButton}> join</Button>
  <p className={styles.textFollow}>Follow us</p>
  <FacebookIcon className={styles.socialIcon} />
  <TwitterIcon className={styles.socialIcon} />
  <InstagramIcon className={styles.socialIcon} />
  <LinkedInIcon className={styles.socialIcon} />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't change anything

Comment: you changed this to a div? `<p className={styles.textFollow}>{TextContents.Follow}</p>` try `<div className={styles.textFollow}>{TextContents.Follow}</div`> or if you want it to be a `p`. then add a style saying `margin :0` applied to that `p` element

Comment: yep I did it. Also it's not fixing the alignment of the textFollow after the button. The text is still at the same place.

Comment: hmm interesting. are you able to create a sandbox just for this? I might be able to play around and fix it in there for you

Comment: try this : https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bash-gq6pq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Seb the problem was when you made the window smaller `follow us` was taking 2 lines. try adding: `minWidth: '100px'` to `textFollow`. it should fix it. it looks good on my machine now

Comment: or you could use `minWidth: 75px` if you want it to be closer to the icons

Comment: it fix the issue of the text, thanks a lot but the text is still below the button and not aligned on its right

Comment: what do you want to achieve sorry? do you mean the "Join" button? where do you want this to be?

Comment: I need the form then the join button and after the text.

Comment: All should be aligned in one single line

Comment: @Seb check image in my answer . do you want it like that?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @Seb please check now if that works for you. under `edit ====` in my answer

Comment: @Seb mind marking this answer as correct if it's finished now so people know to ignore it? thanks